# How to print a variable within an array using its index

Tags: python, arrays, variables, syntax

I am practicing with for in loops and having trouble with this.

```
places = ["phuket", "athens", "doha"]

for places in range(5):
    if places == 0:
        print("thailand," + places 0 + "is a cool place")
    else:
        print("not thailand")
```

When I try this, I get a syntax error with 'places 0'. I want it to print thailand, phuket, is a cool place. But no matter how I seem to format places 0 (with the 0 in [], with it in ()) I just keep getting syntax errors.

Comment: Use `places[0]` and name your `for` loop variable something other than `places` so that you don't have conflicting names, eg: `for i in range(5)` is a more standard naming convention

Comment: This worked thank you Nick. Can you submit this as an answer so I can approve it?

Comment: No worries, your self-answer below looks good to me :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use enumerate you can get the index of the for loop.
**i** will be **0, 1, 2** and **place** will be **phuket, athens, doha**.
And you can use different logic depends on what you want.

```
places = ["phuket", "athens", "doha"]

for i,place in enumerate(places):
    if i == 0:
        print("thailand," + place + "is a cool place")
    else:
        print("not thailand")
```

You can understand more here - https://realpython.com/python-enumerate/

Answer (score 2):

Use places[0] and name your for loop variable something other than places so that you don't have conflicting names, eg: for i in range(5) is a more standard naming convention –  - Nick Parsons. This was the correct answer:

```
places = ["phuket", "athens", "doha"]

for index in range(5):
    if index == 0:
        print("thailand, " + places[0] + "is a cool place")
    else:
        print("not thailand")
```

Answer (score 1):

You would need to use the `places` list in the `for` loop, as well as use the correct syntax for checking the `if` condition:

```
places = ["phuket", "athens", "doha"]

for place in places:
    if place == "phuket":
        print("thailand, " + place + " is a cool place")
    else:
        print("not thailand")
```

Answer (score 0):

When you use this for syntax it returns the value and not the index so your test should be

```
if place == "phuket":
```

Comment: That isn't correct, when you use `for places in range(5):`,  `places` is the "index", not the value. You seem to be thinking of `for place in places:` ?

Comment: right but I want to build it not so that it cites 'phuket' specifically but whatever places[0] is

Comment: So if places[0]=="London" what do you want to print? Where does the text to print come from? Or do you want to test whether places contains Phuket.

Answer (score 0):

Two simplest methods are below which can solve you problem easily:

**Ist method**

[image]

**IInd method**

[image]